# Show reports with Tableau Javascript API with Trusted Authentication

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, tableau-api

I am making reports for clients with Tableau server with Trusted Authentication.

- Client has DHCP
- My Web Server's IP registor in Tableau Server for Trusted IP Addresses
- Using Javascript API with Trusted Authentication

Idea is this, client can see the reports without login.
Does it work?

[image: This is my Idea with Tableau Trusted Authentication with Javascript API]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the basic architecture*. Yes it works.

You have to map external users to a user that Tableau knows about when creating a ticket, so if you want to limit access in some way, you'll have to layer those rules on top -- which can be easy or hard, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want anyone to have access, the easiest approach is to turn on the guest user feature in Tableau server (available for core license installations). In that case, you can skip the whole trusted ticket authentication step.

'*' except that after the user's browser session has a trusted ticket token, the session can interact with the Tableau server directly without using the static web server as an intermediary. So the web server can serve up the HTML, CSS and Javascript originally for the page, but get out of the way of any interactive exploration of the Tableau visualization (which is usually in an iframe)